# Why are older versions of my PyPI-installed package being downloaded?

Tags: google-bigquery, pypi

I have a `PyPi` package that I have updated several times. If you look at the package on `PyPi` you will see that the lastest version is **0.0.4.post0**, installed on 9/15/2023:

[image]

Being curious as to whether anyone has been installing this lately, I have run the following Google BigQuery to see the download counts for the last 30 days grouped by date and release version:

```sql
SELECT DATE(`timestamp`) as download_date, file.version as version, count(*) as download_count
FROM `bigquery-public-data.pypi.file_downloads`
WHERE
  file.project = 'mycgi'
  -- Only query the last 30 days of history
  AND DATE(`timestamp`) >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY download_date, version
ORDER BY download_date DESC, version ASC
```

The results are shown below. **I am trying to understand why the versions being downloaded, for example yesterday 2/18/2023, are not exclusively the most current release, which has been available for approximately 5 months.** I know that in principle one can go to https://pypi.org/simple/mycgi/ and see a list of wheels and tarballs for the various versions. But I would think that anyone installing the package with `pip install mycgi` would get the latest version and I would expect that is how most people would be installing the package. Am I wrong? **A majority of the downloads done in the last 30 days are *not* the latest version. What could account for this? I really do not want to see new installers downloading anything other than the latest version unless it is intentional.**

---

| download_date | version | download_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-02-18 | 0.0.2.post1 | 2 |
| 2024-02-18 | 0.0.2.post2 | 2 |
| 2024-02-18 | 0.0.3 | 2 |
| 2024-02-18 | 0.0.4 | 4 |
| 2024-02-18 | 0.0.4.post0 | 4 |
| 2024-02-17 | 0.0.2.post1 | 1 |
| 2024-02-17 | 0.0.4.post0 | 1 |
| 2024-02-16 | 0.0.4.post0 | 1 |
| 2024-02-15 | 0.0.2.post2 | 1 |
| 2024-02-15 | 0.0.4 | 1 |
| 2024-02-14 | 0.0.2.post1 | 2 |
| 2024-02-14 | 0.0.4.post0 | 2 |
| 2024-02-13 | 0.0.4.post0 | 10 |
| 2024-02-12 | 0.0.4.post0 | 5 |
| 2024-02-11 | 0.0.2.post1 | 2 |
| 2024-02-11 | 0.0.2.post2 | 2 |
| 2024-02-11 | 0.0.3 | 2 |
| 2024-02-11 | 0.0.4 | 2 |
| 2024-02-11 | 0.0.4.post0 | 2 |
| 2024-02-10 | 0.0.2.post1 | 2 |
| 2024-02-10 | 0.0.2.post2 | 2 |
| 2024-02-10 | 0.0.3 | 2 |
| 2024-02-10 | 0.0.4 | 2 |
| 2024-02-10 | 0.0.4.post0 | 2 |
| 2024-02-09 | 0.0.2.post1 | 6 |
| 2024-02-09 | 0.0.2.post2 | 6 |
| 2024-02-09 | 0.0.3 | 6 |
| 2024-02-09 | 0.0.4 | 6 |
| 2024-02-09 | 0.0.4.post0 | 7 |
| 2024-02-08 | 0.0.4.post0 | 4 |
| 2024-02-07 | 0.0.4.post0 | 10 |
| 2024-02-06 | 0.0.4.post0 | 9 |
| 2024-02-05 | 0.0.2.post1 | 6 |
| 2024-02-05 | 0.0.2.post2 | 6 |
| 2024-02-05 | 0.0.3 | 6 |
| 2024-02-05 | 0.0.4 | 6 |
| 2024-02-05 | 0.0.4.post0 | 8 |
| 2024-02-04 | 0.0.2.post1 | 2 |
| 2024-02-04 | 0.0.2.post2 | 2 |
| 2024-02-04 | 0.0.3 | 2 |
| 2024-02-04 | 0.0.4 | 2 |
| 2024-02-04 | 0.0.4.post0 | 4 |
| 2024-02-03 | 0.0.2.post1 | 4 |
| 2024-02-03 | 0.0.2.post2 | 4 |
| 2024-02-03 | 0.0.3 | 5 |
| 2024-02-03 | 0.0.4 | 4 |
| 2024-02-03 | 0.0.4.post0 | 4 |
| 2024-02-02 | 0.0.4.post0 | 1 |
| 2024-02-01 | 0.0.4.post0 | 7 |
| 2024-01-31 | 0.0.4.post0 | 2 |
| 2024-01-30 | 0.0.2.post2 | 1 |
| 2024-01-30 | 0.0.4 | 1 |
| 2024-01-30 | 0.0.4.post0 | 10 |
| 2024-01-29 | 0.0.2.post1 | 6 |
| 2024-01-29 | 0.0.2.post2 | 6 |
| 2024-01-29 | 0.0.3 | 7 |
| 2024-01-29 | 0.0.4 | 7 |
| 2024-01-29 | 0.0.4.post0 | 10 |
| 2024-01-28 | 0.0.4.post0 | 2 |
| 2024-01-27 | 0.0.2.post1 | 2 |
| 2024-01-27 | 0.0.2.post2 | 2 |
| 2024-01-27 | 0.0.3 | 2 |
| 2024-01-27 | 0.0.4 | 2 |
| 2024-01-27 | 0.0.4.post0 | 4 |
| 2024-01-26 | 0.0.4.post0 | 3 |
| 2024-01-24 | 0.0.2.post1 | 2 |
| 2024-01-24 | 0.0.2.post2 | 2 |
| 2024-01-24 | 0.0.3 | 2 |
| 2024-01-24 | 0.0.4 | 2 |
| 2024-01-24 | 0.0.4.post0 | 1 |
| 2024-01-23 | 0.0.2.post1 | 2 |
| 2024-01-23 | 0.0.2.post2 | 2 |
| 2024-01-23 | 0.0.3 | 2 |
| 2024-01-23 | 0.0.4 | 2 |
| 2024-01-23 | 0.0.4.post0 | 6 |
| 2024-01-22 | 0.0.2.post1 | 2 |
| 2024-01-22 | 0.0.2.post2 | 3 |
| 2024-01-22 | 0.0.3 | 3 |
| 2024-01-22 | 0.0.4 | 3 |
| 2024-01-22 | 0.0.4.post0 | 7 |
| 2024-01-21 | 0.0.2.post1 | 6 |
| 2024-01-21 | 0.0.2.post2 | 8 |
| 2024-01-21 | 0.0.3 | 10 |
| 2024-01-21 | 0.0.4 | 10 |
| 2024-01-21 | 0.0.4.post0 | 14 |
| 2024-01-20 | 0.0.4.post0 | 2 |

Comment: The numbers are so low, I wonder if they are significant. -- There are probably a bunch of bots (scrapers) that download all versions. -- Some (real) users might have pinned their dependency requirements to an specific version of your library. -- If it makes sense you can "[yank](https://pypi.org/help/#yanked)" things ([more details](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/simple-repository-api/#adding-yank-support-to-the-simple-api)).

Comment: For what its worth, when the package was first released the download counts were significantly higher. But I will check out your link.